# How to find all words followed by symbol using Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I need `re.findall` to detect words that are followed by `a "="`

So it works for an example like

```
re.findall('\w+(?=[=])', "I think Python=amazing")
```

but it won't work for "I think Python = amazing" or "Python =amazing"...
I do not know how to possibly integrate the whitespace issue here properly.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This and your prior question are a clumsy approach to the refactoring that it appears you really want to do. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: I have indeed abandoned the initial idea of replacing Python-variables by a script that actually "understands" Python and decided to prefer the "clumsy approach" of a script just detecting variables by seeing them as the "one word that is followed by a =". I am now working on a more global regex to extract variable names from different scripts more in a research than a programming context. Thanks a lot for the help and the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'(\w+)\s*=\s*'
re.findall('(\w+)\s*=\s*', 'I think Python=amazing')   \\ return 'Python'
re.findall('(\w+)\s*=\s*', 'I think Python = amazing') \\ return 'Python'
re.findall('(\w+)\s*=\s*', 'I think Python =amazing')  \\ return 'Python'
```

Answer (score 3):

You said "Again stuck in the regex" probably in reference to your earlier question [Looking for a way to identify and replace Python variables in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955665/looking-for-a-way-to-identify-and-replace-python-variables-in-a-script) where you got answers to the question that you asked, but I don't think you asked the question you really wanted the answer to.

You are looking to refactor Python code, and unless your tool *understands* Python, it will generate false positives and false negatives; that is, finding instances of `variable =` that aren't assignments and missing assignments that aren't matched by your regexp.

There is a partial list of tools at [What refactoring tools do you use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796/what-refactoring-tools-do-you-use-for-python) and more general searches with "refactoring Python your_editing_environment" will yield more still.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some optional whitespace before the `=`:

```
\w+(?=\s*=)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this instead**

```
 re.findall('^(.+)(?=[=])', "I think Python=amazing")
```

**Explanation**

```
# ^(.+)(?=[=])
# 
# Options: case insensitive
# 
# Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.+)»
#    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=[=])»
#    Match the character “=” «[=]»
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for whitespace between the word and the `=`:

```
re.findall('\w+(?=\s*[=])', "I think Python = amazing")
```

You can also simplify the expression by using a capturing group around the word, instead of a non-capturing group around the equals:

```
re.findall('(\w+)\s*=', "I think Python = amazing")
```

Answer (score 0):

`r'(.*)=.*'` would do it as well ...

You have anything #1 followed with a `=` followed with anything #2, you get anything #1.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(.*)=.*', "I think Python=amazing")
['I think Python']
>>> re.findall(r'(.*)=.*', "  I think Python =    amazing oh yes very amazing   ")
['  I think Python ']
>>> re.findall(r'(.*)=.*', "=  crazy  ")
['']
```

Then you can `strip()` the string that is in the list returned.

Answer (score -1):

```
re.split(r'\s*=', "I think Python=amazing")[0].split() # returns ['I', 'think', 'Python']
```